# Custom toolbar buttons for different highlighter colors

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Can I use JavaScript to create custom toolbar buttons for different highlighter colors in Adobe Acrobat DC?

Comment: please add...what you have done so far?

Comment: @Darshak I've searched and found that I can use Javascript to change annotations in PDF to a different color.But is it possible to use Javascript to create toolbar buttons for different highlighter colors?

Comment: It's not possible to change the default or initial color of an annotation via JavaScript. However, you can use JavaScript to add a toolbar button that will change the color of the last highlight annotation created. You can have one of these buttons for any number colors you need. That's actually pretty easy. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @joelgeraci Thank you. If I want to change the initial color of an annotation, is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: In the annotation properties dialog, you can check a box to make the current properties the default. There's no way to do it programmatically from within Acrobat.

Comment: @joelgeraci Thank you.